Sleep API is not getting subscribed on android real device
I integrated sleep api in android to get users sleep intervals, but facing error at the time of subscription on real device. on emulator it successfully subscribed but I can not test on emulator.
I have tested on real devices on OS 11 iTel and OS 14 Samsung , its not getting subscribed in any of my device
the code runs on the emulator but I cannot test and get sleep intervals on emulator.
it is the same issue mentioned here
https://github.com/android/location-samples/issues/275
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 16:

at 
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus( 
com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.4.0:3)

at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.TaskUtil.
setResultOrApiException(
com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.4.0:4)

at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.TaskUtil.
setResultOrApiException(
com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.4.0:1)

at com.google.android.gms.internal.location.zzah.onResult(
com.google.android.gms:play-services-location@@21.2.0:1)

at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.
IStatusCallback$Stub.zaa(com.google.android.gms:play-services- 
base@@18.4.0:3)

at com.google.android.gms.internal.base.zab.onTransact(
com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.4.0:3)

at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1380)

at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1311)

